# change local URL based on dopdown list

Tags: javascript, url, drop-down-menu

I want to change the local URL (on/of the same page) from

> example.php

to

> example.php?month=year-month

I have following script:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  function select() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var year = document.getElementById('myyear').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('mymonth').value;
    document.my_months.action = url + '?month=' + year + '-' + month;
  }
</script>
```

And follwing form:

```
echo "<form id =\"my_months\" name= \"my_months\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"return select();\">
  <select name = \"myyear\" id = \"myyear\">";

  foreach (range(2012, date('Y')) as $years) {
    if ($years == date('Y')) {
      echo "<option value= \"".$years."\" selected= \"".$years."\">".$years."</option>";
    } else {
      echo "<option value= \"".$years."\">".$years."</option>";
    }
  }
  echo "</select>
        <select name = \"mymonth\"> id = \"mymonth\"";

  foreach ($myMonths as $id => $months) {
    if ($months == date('F')) {
      echo "<option value= \"".$id."\" selected= \"".$id."\">".$months."</option>";
    } else {
      echo "<option value= \"".$id."\">".$months."</option>";
    }
  }
  echo "</select>
  <input type=\"submit\" id=\"Submit_m\" name=\"Submit_m\" value=\"Ok\">
</form>";
```

But it doesn't work. The page will be reload without modifying the URL!
What I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
echo "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\">
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <meta name=\"description\" content=\"\" />
  <meta name=\"robots\" content=\"index,follow\" />
  <meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"\" />
  <!--<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5\">-->
  <script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"../js/jquery-1.9.1.js\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"../js/modules/exporting.js\"></script>
  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function select() {
      var url = window.location.href;
      var year = document.getElementById('myyear').value;
      var month = document.getElementById('mymonth').value;
      document.my_months.action = url + '?month=' + year + '-' + month;
    }
  </script>
  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $(document).ready(
      function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            zoomType: 'xy'
          },
...
        });
      }
    )
  </script>
</head>
<body>";

//here some data and arrays

echo "<form id =\"my_months\" name= \"my_months\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"return select();\">
  <select name = \"myyear\" id = \"myyear\">";

  foreach (range(2012, date('Y')) as $years) {
    if ($years == date('Y')) {
      echo "<option value= \"".$years."\" selected= \"".$years."\">".$years."</option>";
    } else {
      echo "<option value= \"".$years."\">".$years."</option>";
    }
  }
  echo "</select>
        <select name = \"mymonth\"> id = \"mymonth\"";

  foreach ($myMonths as $id => $months) {
    if ($months == date('F')) {
      echo "<option value= \"".$id."\" selected= \"".$id."\">".$months."</option>";
    } else {
      echo "<option value= \"".$id."\">".$months."</option>";
    }
  }
  echo "</select>
  <input type=\"submit\" id=\"Submit_m\" name=\"Submit_m\" value=\"Ok\">
</form>
<p><div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: 200px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto\"></div></p></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all suggested tries were not successfull. However I've changed the **method of the form** from **post** to **get** and the url changed to

> example.php?myyear=myyear_value&mymonth=mymonth_value&Submit_m=OK

whwn submiting the button named **Submit_m**

With these variables I'm now abel to the get the values with **$_GET['myyear']** and **$_GET['mymonth']**

Now I get the behavior expected

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  function select() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var year = document.getElementById('myyear').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('mymonth').value;
    url += '?month=' + year + '-' + month;

    // set the url in your location bar
    history.pushState({date:"true"}, "", url);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: did not work too :-(

It is possible that it interact with other javascripts on this page?

I have another javascript, that implement a graph by using Highcharts Library. This script is included between $(document).ready( function () { new chart .... } )

Comment: @user2545384, can you be more specific? Try splitting off the the url file name to use instead of the entire url.